# tmux - split panes and ssh to multiple servers via script

Tags: tmux

I would like to automate the following steps that I am currently performing manually.

In a terminal, I perform these steps:

1. start tmux
2. split into 10 panes
3. tile the panes
4. navigate to each pane and ssh into a server, repeat 10 times
5. synchronize the panes

Is there a way to script all this, including the 10 different ssh login commands?

Comment: What have you tried? The tmux manual tells you how to do all of this, e.g. `tmux split-window` will create a new pane, and `tmux send-keys` can send commands to start an ssh session.

Comment: `tmux new-window ssh server01.local \; split-pane -h ssh server02.local ` to create a new window with 2 splits with different ssh session each. maybe this can be extended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `new-session` and `split-pane` commands in `tmux` take a command to run in the new pane.  If you have a list of `user@server` strings in an array, you could do this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ssh_list=( user1@server1 user2@server2 ... )

split_list=()
for ssh_entry in "${ssh_list[@]:1}"; do
    split_list+=( split-pane ssh "$ssh_entry" ';' )
done

tmux new-session ssh "${ssh_list[0]}" ';' \
    "${split_list[@]}" \
    select-layout tiled ';' \
    set-option -w synchronize-panes
```

This creates a list of `split-pane` commands that split the current pane and run `ssh` to one of the servers in the list `ssh_list`.  We create one such command for each of the listed servers, except for the first one (which we will use with the `new-session` command instead).

The `tmux` command at the end creates a new session and runs the first `ssh` command, does all the splits, rearranges the panes according to the `tiled` layout ([see the `tmux` manual for alternatives](https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#even-horizontal)), and enables synchronisation of the panes.

The `tmux` session will terminate once all `ssh` sessions have terminated.

---

Update: Interestingly, the `tmux(1)` manual *does not mention a `split-pane` command*.  The above code still works though, but if you're using an older version of `tmux`, you may want to change `split-pane` into `split-window` (since `tmux` 2.4, `split-pane` and `splitp` are synonyms for `split-window`).

Comment: how would you go about naming the panes?
I saw that it's not trivial to name them. Opening a bunch of windows instead is also an option. but the automatic naming is important for me. For example, name them based on the host name (or simply by enumeration)